# java.net.UnknownHostException while running RestAssured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am Running Below Code & getting following exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: maps.googleapis.com
>       at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)

I tried to check the same in CMD in order to check DNS issue . Can anyone suggest how we can resolve this "can't find maps.googleapis.com: Non-existent domain" issue.

I tried to check the DNS issue in using "nslookup maps.googleapis.com" CMD but I am getting the error "find https://maps.googleapis.com: Non-existent domain".

Code:

```
RestAssured.baseURI="https://maps.googleapis.com";

given().
        param("location","-33.8670522,151.1957362").
        param("radius","1500").
        param("type","restaurant").
        param("keyword","cruise").
        param("key","AIzaSyA4HVDos-DFWuFJDmHNn8qlKBrRNSgAhtc").
        when().
        get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").
        then().assertThat().
        statusCode(250);
```

Expected- Should get response

Actual- Unable to run the code due to 'UnknownHostException'.

Comment: The most logical explanation is that the host is actually unknown. In your network, at least. Can be caused by a firewall for example. Do a google for *"https://maps.googleapis.com unknown host"*, you'll find you are not alone.

Comment: I am executing the code in my Office Network. Also, when I try to look up in CMD using command 'nslookup maps.googleapis.com' in order to check if DNS is able to resolve the issue, but getting pop up 'can't find https://maps.googleapis.com: Non-existent domain'.  I think if i got the resolution of 'Non Existent Domain Issue', then it may work. Due you have any resolution for it ?

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but you might try setting the forcing the IP resolution in your hosts file. If it works that way, then it's an issue with the host resolution...

Comment: @JasonWarner- Aplologies, but did not get 'Forcing the IP Resolution', can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Can anyone suggest a solution using try/catch block. I tried but java says: Exception 'java.net.UnknownHostException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block